# How can I create a globally adjusted sampling distribution based on the regions of Morocco?

Tags: sampling, data-mining, excel

I have a table of population statistics from Burundi with the following:

Province -- Population -- Sample Distribution -- Global Sample (Distribution Adjusted)

The table continues with each province listed. The total sample is 1500.

I would like to create a similar table for Morocco in Excel except with a total sample size of 2000 and including an Urban/Rural breakdown. I have the population by province (but not the urban rural variable).

Can anyone show me how to create the sample distribution globally adjusted sample in Excel? Also, if anyone is familiar with data mining and knows where I can find urban/rural breakdowns for countries (Morocco) by province any help would be appreciated.